# Error when rendering FlatList with default props Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get this error when I import anduse flatList in my react-native app.

```
import { Text, FlatList  } from 'react-native'
```

My FlatList Component:

```
<FlatList
 data={responseData}
 renderItem={({node}) => <Text style={} >{node.nameWithOwner}</Text>}/>
```

I dont get an error when Rendering the FlatList without any props
from the expo simulator screen.

When only using data prop and not the renderItem prop I get `renderItem is not a function`

[image: img_20171029_083459]

```
abi21_0_0.com.facebook.react.common .JavascriptException: Failed 
to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 
'http://1 92.1 68.0.1 3:19001/ node_modules/react-native-
scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=expo/tools/ hashAssetFiles' failed to load.
Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script 
at 'http:// 192.168.0.13:19001/node_modules/reactnative-
scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&strict=false&minify=faIse&hot=false&assetPlugin=
expoltoolsl hashAssetFiles' failed to load.
loadApplicationScript WebsocketJavaScriptExecutor.java:173
run NativeRunnable.java
```

Something like this facebook/react-native#13558  and this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6035 and https://github.com/bnovf/react-native-github-graphql-app/issues/3

Is this a problem with FlatList itself?

Answer (score 1):

solved by changging the renderItem prop function

```
     <FlatList
      data={responseData}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text >{item.node.nameWithOwner}</Text>}
    />
```